# Is there any site with telescopes data?

Tags: telescope, data-analysis, raw-data

Is the data gathered from telescopes "open source"? If so, is there any website that group it all?

Comment: Hi, before asking a wide-range question like this, please take some time to review existing sites and figure out what sort of data you're looking for, what kind of formats, and so on.  As it stands, this is far too vague to be able to answer.

Comment: I meant the raw data, like, if there every data we collect on every telescope in raw data, do we have something like this? Or only focused ones?

Comment: Have you tried looking? e.g. by typing "European Southern Observatory Database" or "Keck Observatory database" into google?

Comment: The fact that you don't understand what the "raw data" can be is indicative of the reason I asked you to do more research.  You might find visible images, near-IR images, radiotelescope data,  raw and corrected data from adaptive optics systems, and lots more.

Comment: I mean, all the examples you gave me the raw data is the same, electromagnetic waves, different waves length doesn't change the type of the raw data, I guess you didn't understand what I meant by raw

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Most general purpose observatories release the data taken on their facilities after the expiration of the proprietary period (this is the time, typically 12-18 months, where the data is only available to the proposers for the telescope time so they can work on it without being "scooped"). "Focused telescopes" in the sense of those that are performing surveys or looking for specific types of objects, tend **not** to release the raw data, instead releasing processed data or catalogs.

Some examples of data archives that provide raw or processed data include:

- the [NOAO Science Archive](http://archive1.dm.noao.edu/): provides access to 40 telescope+instrument combination from the US National Optical Astronomy Observatory
- the [ESO Science Archive Facility](http://archive.eso.org/cms.html): access to raw and processed data from the four 8-m VLT telescopes plus the VLTI and the smaller (1-3.6m) telescopes on La Silla, Chile
- the [MAST archive at StSci](https://archive.stsci.edu/missions-and-data): contains data from Hubble, Kepler and K2, TESS, SwiftUVOT, XMM and many others
- the [ING archive](http://casu.ast.cam.ac.uk/casuadc/ingarch/query): for the Isaac Newton Group of telescopes of La Palma (1.0m JKT, 2.5m INT, 4.2m WHT telescopes)

Querying multiple archives for data is the role of the Virtual Observatory; there is a page of links to [tools at SAAO](https://www.saao.ac.za/resources/virtual-observatory/) and the [Data Discovery Tool](http://www.virtualobservatory.org/use/)

Comment: Good answer! This should be a community wiki answer, along maybe with a similar one about how to get the data with VO tools

Comment: @BruceBecker It's not fair (IMO) to pressure members into potentially loosing points by [making a post a community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts).  Note that members can (quite reasonably) be aiming to accumulate particular reputation scores to access specific privileges, often to the long term benefit of the community as a whole because of the nature of those privileges.

Comment: My aim was to praise, not pressure, but as I'm aware that it may have the effect you describe, I humbly retract my suggestion. @astrosnapper deserves all their points. In a few minutes, I may delete the comment too.

Comment: I like the idea of a community wiki to provide curated answers to regular questions but 1) it seems that the reputation system doesn't reward this and 2) maybe it's just my newbie lack of experience, but it seems very non-obvious on how to get to the wiki